# Unity Project Architecture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, coding-style, game-development

I am developing a 2D Platformer RPG Game. The game will have many characters in it, each having different abilities (or powers). My question is that how can I maintain my project structure so that I can add as many charcters or abilities I want to add in the future without making a complete mess of my code.

For example:
I have a charcter lets say Iron-Man so I want him to use thrusters but let say there is another player using Captain America as his character who cant use thrusters.
Now how to make a system so that I can add characters and abilities or have characters exchange any ability with another at runtime?

I've heard about using interfaces to make code cleaner and also about using scriptable objects but I haven't quite worked with them.

I would like to know a concrete method of making this type of system (If there is any).

**Any links to tutorials would be appreciated.**

PS- My game has just 1 character in it and everyday I open my project hoping that I will add a new character but I am always afraid that I will break my code and I think that if I surf a little more on the internet I will get a proper sturcture to start with so I dont take any risk and I just end up changing some things here and there and close it.

Comment: Lists and abstract classes. And the most important of all: think ahead.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check out (Mainly related to OOP):

**SOLID design and Design Patterns Videos**

1. https://unity3d.college/2017/11/24/solid-unity3d-code-architecture-open-closed-principal/
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGVkio4bnPQ
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoNumkMTx-U
4. Lots more in his channel, those were just a few

**Design Patterns Code to study**

1. https://github.com/Naphier/unity-design-patterns
2. https://github.com/QianMo/Unity-Design-Pattern

**Lastly:**

1. Unity's Free (For next month or so) learning: https://learn.unity.com/

Comment: Are there any intermediate level books you would like to recommend?